# Java MySQL get last row

Tags: java, mysql, chat

So I'm having issues with my program. Basically this far the program is like a MySQL based chat. It stores messages in database and reads them. I'm having problems with the reading. What it does right now is ever 5 seconds re-read all the messages in the database. I tried to make it read only the new messages but that's not working out too well. This is my code:

```
public static void readChat()
{
    try
    {
        MySQL.sqlConnect();
        try
        {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table1");
            while (res.next())
            {
                if (lastLine < res.getInt("id"))
                {
                    String message = res.getString("message");
                    Gui.out.append(message + "\n");
                    lastLine = res.getInt("id");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {   
            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
        }
        MySQL.sqlDisconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to make this efficient. It takes way too long to execute that. If the id is 23 I can't even see the messages appear because it takes longer than 5 seconds. I added the

```
if (lastLine < res.getInt("id"))
```

and

```
lastLine = res.getInt("id");
```

in my effort to make it read only the new messages but it did not work as expected. I think it still executed line by line, just doesn't show it in the chat. There's got to be an easier way.

EDIT: Alright, so I fixed the problem with not seeing messages, (I forgot to remove the part of the code that cleared the chat every 5 seconds). But it still takes a long time to send messages, about 3-4 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and you will wonder :)

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table1 where id > "+lastLine);
```

instad

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table1");
```

and get result without if

```
       while (res.next())
        {
                String message = res.getString("message");
                Gui.out.append(message + "\n");
                lastLine = res.getInt("id");
        }
```

Of course make sure index on id field

Comment: This solution could mean you are missing updates from different transactions though.

Answer (score 1):

you can just read the required rows, currently you are reading all the rows try following,

```
public static void readChat()
{
    try
    {
        MySQL.sqlConnect();
        try
        {
            Statement st = con.Preparestatment("SELECT * FROM  table1 where id > ?");
        st.setInt(0,lastLine);
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
            while (res.next())
            {
                String message = res.getString("message");
                Gui.out.append(message + "\n");
                lastLine = res.getInt("id");
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {   
            System.out.println("SQL code does not execute.");
        }
        MySQL.sqlDisconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yah, something similar to Alexey's method. Im just a bit slow.

Answer (score 1):

You still iterate through all results. If you have some way of storing the time at which messages are sent i.e creating a time column, you can try to shorten how many results are returned by doing

```
ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  table1 WHERE id = ? AND time > ?");
```

where the first ? is the id of the user and the 2nd ? is the time of the last read message. This is based off the assumption id is some unique user id.

Comment: I think the way Alexey did it makes more sense. I was on the right track I just made it loop through all the messages instead of the ones I need.

Answer (score 1):

What about maintaining a list, add new message to that list when you save it to the database and just read the new messages from that list and clear it at the end of readChat()?

Comment: Just makes that too much maintenance, Alexey's method works fine